# Importing HTML into HTML using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, import

### Is it possible to import HTML templates into another HTML file using webpack?

### If so How?

I am trying to import HTML files to create some kind of basic templating.

The setup is using webpack to bundle my JS.

I have tried looking into HtmlWebpackPlugin and a bunch of others but they never show an example of this use case.

Is there an easy option I can use to plugin an HTML templating engine that will allow me to using includes in my HTML file? If so what is it and how do I set this up?

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- I want to include templates here -->
        <!-- I want to include templates here -->
        <!-- I want to include templates here -->
        <script src="bundle.main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './dev/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.main.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                loader: 'ejs-html-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dev"),
        compress: true,
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

As you can see I am trying here to get ejs working but I am having no success. I don't necessarily need to use ejs it's just an example.

I feel like I am missing a step here.

If anyone could help me here I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I think this is what HtmlWebpackPlugin is meant to do: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin  ... literally even uses EJS :)

Comment: @olore a working example would answer my question

Answer (score 1):

I may be 6 years late in responding to this question, but I stumbled upon it today while searching for the same answer. Eventually, I found the answer myself, so I decided to post it here in case anyone else comes across this question.

I use the *HtmlWebpackPlugin* in combination with the *fs* module from Node.js. The **webpack.config.js** file looks something like this:

```js
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');
...

// Read partials
const partial = fs.readFileSync('./src/partials/partial.html', 'utf8');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),
    },    
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
        clean: true,
        assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Index - title',
            partial: partial,
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Template1 - title',
            partial: partial,
            filename: 'template1.html',
            template: 'src/template1.html'
        }),
        ...
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Then, to access the *HtmlWebpackPlugin* options as specified above in the **index.html** or the **template1.html** for instance, we just need to add this into our HTML files:

```
<body>
  ...
  <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.partial %>
  ...
</body>
```

It can also be seen in the example that the HTML title is defined in the **webpack.config.js** file and the value used in the HTML as follows:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
  </head>
```

For the use case of the original question, I redirected the HTML as a string directly from the **partial.html** file with the use of the *fs* module to read it and assign it to a variable:

```
const partial = fs.readFileSync('./src/partials/partial.html', 'utf8');
```

I hope someone finds this useful. Also, if someone else knows a better way to do it, please share!